# How to edit existing .docx in Google Docs without losing columns

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I have an existing `.docx` file in Google Drive that is formatted with columns (not a table with columns, but just multiple page columns). When I open it in a Google Docs editor, the columns disappear (it becomes one column).

Is there a way in Google Drive to edit the document *without* losing the columns?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, sorry.

The closest is; managing a 1x2 table. (Size, color etc.) Including, sadly, manual continuation of content in column 2.